# Match HTML open tags between quotes

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have small html code bellow:

```
<span class="k">function</span> () { <span class="k">this</span>.test = '<p><span>test</span></p>'; }
```

and this regex:

```
/["|'](<)|(<)(?:\/[^>]>)["|']/g
```

With this regex, it returns two matched results, but what I want is to match all html open tags between the quotes and group them into one result. What is the correct regex to do so?
I need to replace those open tags with `&lt;` after.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Don't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Use an HTML parser instead, like the one that's made available to JavaScript by the browser you're using.

Comment: In general, you should [not try parsing HTML with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1995300) (HTML does not have a regular grammar). Have you considered using an HTML parser.

Comment: Problem is, I'm not sure that this will parse as HTML, since it has tags inside the quoted string, which will throw the HTML parser off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex to get the `<` symbol inside the single quotation marks:

```
(?=[^']*'[^']*$)<
```

See [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/uD6uR3/1).

**Explanation**:
The positive lookahead checks if the `<` symbol is followed by 1 `'` and there are no other single quotation marks. So, this means, the regex will only work well if there is 1 group of words inside single quotation marks. To account for any other cases, this should be fine-tuned.

You can replace the `<`s with

```
var str = '<span class="k">function</span> () { <span class="k">this</span>.test = \'<p><span>test</span></p>\'; }';
var result = str.replace(/(?=[^']*'[^']*$)</g, '&lt;');
```

And later all `>`s:

```
result = result.replace(/(?=[^']*'[^']*$)>/g, '&gt;');
```

Snippet (you will see `<` and `>` symbols):

```js
var str = '<span class="k">function</span> () { <span class="k">this</span>.test = \'<p><span>test</span></p>\'; }';
var result = str.replace(/(?=[^']*'[^']*$)</g, '&lt;');
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = result.replace(/(?=[^']*'[^']*$)>/g, '&gt;');
```

```html
<div id="res"/>
```

Comment: You are welcome. I have added the sample code as well.

Comment: But can you explain yours please? :)

Comment: I've added the explanation now.

Comment: This seems unnecessarily complicated and limited.

Comment: I think you meant "symbol is _preceded_ by".

Comment: @JamesWilkins: I am using a look-ahead, not a look-behind, thus, it is checking what is after the currently consumed symbol.

Comment: Ah yes of course, sorry, must have been half asleep when I typed that last night. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have "broken" HTML, with HTML tags inside a quoted string. This will make it impossible to parse the string with an HTML parser, as some commenters suggested--they are right in principle, but it won't work in this case.

Where does this fragment of HTML come from? Your best alternative is to escape the HTML inside the quote marks at some earlier point in your workflow, so you don't have to write an ugly regexp to try to untangle it.

If you really want to use regexps to do this, there is no need for some ridiculously hairy regexp. It should suffice to do:

```
str.replace(/'(.*?)'/g, function(_, match) { return esc(match); })
```

How to write `esc`? Well, most libraries have something that does that. Or you could write your own, as another answer suggested. Here's a solution that uses the browser's built-in ability to deal with such things:

```
function esc(str) {
  var e = document.createElement('div');
  e.textContent = str;
  return e.innerHTML;
}
```

This gives you:

```
>> var x = '<span class="k">function</span> () { <span class="k">this</span>.test = \'<p><span>test</span></p>\'; }'
>> x.replace(/'(.*?)'/g, function(_, match) { return esc(match); })
<< "<span class="k">function</span> () { <span class="k">this</span>.test = &lt;p&gt;&lt;span&gt;test&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;; }"
```